# Javascript/jQuery to tell when YouTube is played

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

On http://www.pegstar.net/ we are displaying the videos using the old object code (example code is below) and displaying 15 videos per a page. These are all dynamically generated and looking to upgrade to the iFrame API. One thing we are wondering is how many people are clicking on "play" on the videos. Is there a way to be able to tell this using the old object script or does it have to be updated to the iFrame API?

```
<object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/MIqhbyZ5iZg" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/MIqhbyZ5iZg" /></object>
```

Comment: Have you considered simply using Google Analytics event tracking to get this data?

Comment: I think you would be better off using the iFrame API because it does open up the possibility of tracking a **[number of events](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events)**. Also, you will have to combine that with some analytics engine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went with upgrading the site to using the iFrame. This way I can call a custom page to log my own stats on the user. I don't see a way I can mark any of these as answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, it can at least help you to see appr. count:

```
function playCount() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'play');
}

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('object');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", playCount);
}
```